# Show Records After specific column Value

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery, knex.js

Consider i have a table TBL_AUD and it has a column UTYPE.UTYPE can have value submit, reject and approve.
I want to show records which are entered after UTYPE=approve. Meaning when column UTYPE have 'approve' at any row, i want to show records after that row.
Please help i can't make up the query im not very good at sql.

ID | UTYPE

- 1  | submit
- 2  | reject
- 3  | approve
- 4  | submit
- 5  | reject

like this example above i want all rows after approve

Comment: Do you have a column that orders the rows in your table?

Comment: you mean primary ID??yes

Comment: What happens if you have a submit/reject after approve(ie later ids) you want those too? sample data an expected result as text in the question would help.

Comment: yes i want them too. Just whenever approve enters i want all records after that.

Answer (score 1):

You would first need to find the `ID` of the record after which you want all the records to show. That's a simple query:

```
SELECT ID 
FROM TBL_AUD 
WHERE UTYPE = 'approve' 
ORDER BY ID
LIMIT 1;
```

After that you can use this query as a sub-query to find the records. Let's call the query above `SubQuery`. The search query would then become:

```
SELECT *
FROM TBL_AUD 
WHERE ID > (SubQuery);
```

Or, written out fully:

```
SELECT *
FROM TBL_AUD 
WHERE ID > (SELECT ID 
            FROM TBL_AUD 
            WHERE UTYPE = 'approve' 
            ORDER BY ID
            LIMIT 1);
```

You probably would need to add some extra conditions, to make this do exactly what you want, but your question is not rich on details, so I can't add those.

Comment: im not good in english so i tried my best to explain. I will try your answer sir! Thank you

Comment: I understand. Practice makes perfect. 